# How to get the next 12 months with empty months

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I wanted to get the projected `Balance` for the next 12 months from the current month and if the `Balance` is empty for that month it will get the value from the nearest `Month` with a `Balance` of greater than 0.

```
void Main()
{
    var firstDayMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
    var months = Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
                           .Select(m => new 
                            {
                                Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(m)
                            });

    List<SomeDate> SomeDates = new List<SomeDate>()
    {
        new SomeDate { Id = 1, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(0), Balance = 1m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 2, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(2), Balance = 1m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 3, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(1), Balance = 6m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 4, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(2), Balance = 5m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 5, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(3), Balance = 3m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 6, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(2), Balance = 2m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 7, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(3), Balance = 4m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 8, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(1), Balance = 2m },
        new SomeDate { Id = 9, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(3), Balance = 3m },
    };

    var groupedMonths = SomeDates
                        .GroupBy(c => c.Month)
                        .Select(g => new 
                        {
                            Month = g.Key,
                            SumBalance = g.Sum(s => s.Balance)
                        });

    var Projected12MonthsBalance = from m in months
                                   join gm in groupedMonths on m.Month equals gm.Month into mm
                                   from gm in mm.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                   select new 
                                    {
                                        Month = m.Month, 
                                        Balance = gm == null ? 0m : gm.SumBalance
                                    };

    Console.WriteLine(Projected12MonthsBalance);
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class SomeDate 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Month { get; set; }
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I have tried so far. This would result to:

```
Month     | Balance
7/1/2015  | 1
8/1/2015  | 8
9/1/2015  | 8
10/1/2015 | 10
11/1/2015 | 0
...
6/1/2016  | 0
```

Is it possible to get a result somewhat like this:

```
Month     | Balance
7/1/2015  | 1
8/1/2015  | 8
9/1/2015  | 8
10/1/2015 | 10
11/1/2015 | 10 <-- gets the value from the nearest month with Balance greater than 0
...
6/1/2016  | 10 <-- gets the value from the nearest month with Balance greater than 0
```

I can't seem to complete the query so I've set zeroes for now. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Classical `for(each)` beats LINQ with sequential processing, both in speed and lucidity of code. Just loop through the months and memorize the last one with a non-zero balance.

Comment: Agreed, LINQ is definitely the wrong tool for this type of query.

Comment: @GertArnold - I agree that there is a minor speed improvement with classical techniques, but as far as the lucidity of code goes I would have to disagree - LINQ wins out there in spades IMHO.

Comment: @Enigmativity Maybe it's a matter of taste, but I respectfully disagree.

Comment: @BoyPasmo - You you please confirm how the "nearest month" rule should work? For example, if there is a balance for May & July, what should be used for June?

Comment: @Enigmativity Hi. I think I may have confused you guys. The "nearest month" rule is getting the value from the previous months with balance greater than zero. Say, `June-10`, `July-0`, `Aug-0`, `Sep-5`. Then that should result to `June-10`, `July-10`, `Aug-10`, `Sep-5`. I hope I cleared your confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems rather easy with LINQ, IMHO.

First, I modified `months` to avoid the use of the anonymous type (as it wasn't necessary).

```
var months =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, 12)
        .Select(m => firstDayMonth.AddMonths(m));
```

Then I created a look-up for the balance figures by month:

```
var lookup =
    SomeDates
        .ToLookup(x => x.Month, x => x.Balance);
```

Look-ups are better that group-bys or dictionaries in that you can ask for values of a look-up where the key doesn't exist and it returns an empty list. It alleviates the need to check for the existence of the key before retrieving values.

I'm going to use `.Aggregate(...)` to build the final list, so I need to create the initial `accumulator` for the aggregate function:

```
var accumulator =
    months
        .Take(1)
        .Select(m => new { Month = m, Balance = lookup[m].Sum() })
        .ToList();
```

This is just the result of computing the balance for the first month and adding it to a list. This is a list of an anonymous type.

Now the final query is quite easy:

```
var Projected12MonthsBalance =
    months
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            accumulator,
            (a, m) =>
            {
                var b = lookup[m].Sum();
                b = b == 0 ? a.Last().Balance : b;
                a.Add(new { Month = m, Balance = b });
                return a;
            });
```

This query skips the first month because we already added it to the accumulator. The lamdba function now simply computes the balance for each month and if it is zero it takes the balance from the proceeding month instead.

Here's the result I get:

[image: result]

Comment: He asked for the 'nearest' month, not the preceding month. E.g. If there is no balance for three subsequent months, then the third of those months should take the balance from the fourth month, not from the preceding month with a balance. The gain from the lookup over the dictionary is moot, since you expect to query (and then sum) for every key anyway. Clearer answer than mine though, otherwise.

Comment: @NamelessOne - The gain from the look-up is purely to avoid checking for the existence of the key. I'll have a think about the nearest month.

Comment: Ok, so your assumption is simply that balances will never naturally be 0. That clears that up, thank you. Even though I don't agree with your assumption, I appreciate the elegance it affords.

Comment: @NamelessOne - Sorry, I don't think I've made that assumption. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: The line `b = b == 0 ? a.Last().Balance : b;` assumes the only way to have total balances of `0` is when there were no entries (not say, one entry of `5.0` and another of `-5.0`).

Comment: @NamelessOne - Yes, I see what you mean now. I had assumed that there would be no negative balances.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested above, you can do this more easily with a `foreach` loop. I would construct a dictionary containing totals for months, and where there is no entry for the month, I would use `OrderBy` to retrieve the 'closest' entry as you requested.

```
void main()
{
    var firstDayMonth = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, 1);
    var months = Enumerable.Range(0, 12)
                           .Select(firstDayMonth.AddMonths);

    List<SomeDate> SomeDates = new List<SomeDate>()
                                {
                                    new SomeDate { Id = 1, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(0), Balance = 1m },
                                    new SomeDate { Id = 2, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(2), Balance = 1m },
                                    new SomeDate { Id = 3, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(1), Balance = 6m },
                                    new SomeDate { Id = 4, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(2), Balance = 5m },
                                    new SomeDate { Id = 5, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(3), Balance = 3m },
                                    new SomeDate { Id = 6, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(2), Balance = 2m },
                                    new SomeDate { Id = 7, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(3), Balance = 4m },
                                    new SomeDate { Id = 8, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(1), Balance = 2m },
                                    new SomeDate { Id = 9, Month = firstDayMonth.AddMonths(3), Balance = 3m },
                                };

    var groupedMonths = SomeDates
                        .GroupBy(c => c.Month)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(s => s.Balance));

    var Projected12MonthsBalance = new List<Tuple<DateTime, decimal>>();
    foreach (var month in months)
    {
        decimal balance;
        if (groupedMonths.TryGetValue(month, out balance))
        {
            Projected12MonthsBalance.Add(new Tuple<DateTime, decimal>(month, balance));
        }
        else
        {
            Projected12MonthsBalance.Add(
                new Tuple<DateTime, decimal>(
                    month,
                    groupedMonths.OrderBy(g => g.Key.Subtract(month).Duration()).First().Value));
        }
    }

    foreach (var item in Projected12MonthsBalance)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", item.Item1, item.Item2);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

If you prefer a purely linq solution, the following should work too:

```
var lookup = SomeDates.ToLookup(c => c.Month);

var Projected12MonthsBalance = months.Select(
    month => lookup.OrderBy(g => g.Key.Subtract(month).Duration())
                 .First())
                 .Select(g => new 
                        {
                            Month = g.Key, 
                            Balance = g.Sum(e => e.Balance)
                        });
```